# KDevelop not working properly after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, kde, kdevelop

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10, which upgraded kdevelop to 4.5.1, I see the following error when I start kdevelop:

> Could not start process Cannot talk to klauncher: The name org.kde.klauncher was not provided by any .service files.

This is followed by another error:

> Unable to load the project file /home/drew/foo/some-project.kdev4

The filesystem panel is not populated:

[image]

...and the File Open dialog shows no files or folders:

[image]

Under Ubuntu 13.04, I'd upgraded to a newer version of kdevelop than the default repositories has (4.3.x I believe) and I had to run kdevelop as root in order to make it work correctly. Is it possible that a file was created as the root user, which now causes this problem? I don't know where else to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When previously running KDevelop as root, many files in `~/.kde` and `~/.kdevduchain` were owned by root:

```
find ~/.kde* -user root
```

I got this working by:

- deleting the contents of `~/.kdevduchain`
- recursively `chown`/`chgrp`ing entries in `~/.kde` that were owned by root

After that last step I noticed that there were a bunch of links in that folder, so I'm not sure it's necessary or even a good idea to do that.

I also uninstalled/reinstalled kdevelop, though this might not be necessary.

Now at least, kdevelop is working.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
chown -R "$USER:" ~/.kde
```

Others such as `~/.config` may need it as well.